# Converting search input into date picker

Tags: jquery, jsp

How would I go about converting this into a date picker?

```
<wts:input label="Open Date" inputId="containerOpenDate" path="containerOpenDate" size="12"></wts:input>            
        <wts:input label="Close Date" inputId="containerClosedDate" path="containerClosedDate" size="12"></wts:input>
```

Comment: If you are using `jquery ui`, you can do it with one line of code `$('#containerClosedDate').datepicker();`

Comment: so something like this

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
 $("#containerOpenDate").datepicker();
 $("#containerClosedDate").datepicker();
});
</script>

Comment: Yep, that should do the trick if you are using `jquery ui`

Comment: You are welcome :)